Problem occurred in the android/app/build.gradle .thus this is not specified to the applicationId
enter image description here
What is this issue? I do not understand why it is occurring. While I have successfully maintained all the build.gradle and app/build.gradle file organized.
def localProperties =  new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw newGradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.moto_park"
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
        }
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.moto_park"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 33
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    }
}


What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.


A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AgpDslLockedException: It is too late to set applicationId
It has already been read to configure this project.
Consider either moving this call to be during evaluation,
or using the variant API.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
what is the issuse


Looks like it doesn't like you doing this:
    configurations.all {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.moto_park"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 33
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
      ...
    }

I don't see much of a reason for having that block specified that way.  The values are all static so why not move them to the top of the gradle file like so:
android {
    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.moto_park"
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 33
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVersionName
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

This could've changed because of upgrading flutter too which would necessitate more changes to your build.gradle file(s) to accommodate deprecations.
